# Tab Button Space issue

Tags: html

I'm a new HTML5 coder. Please see the sceenshot below showing my issue
[image]

You can see the blue color drawed inside the circle in this picture.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        <title>Tab Animation</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <div style="width:100%; height:93%; background-color:gray">
                <!--
                <div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:orange"> </div>
                <div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:blueviolet"> </div>
                <div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:yellow"> </div>
                -->
            </div>
            <div style="width:100%; height:7%; background-color:slateblue">

                <div class="tabButton">
                    <div><p>Tab 1</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="tabButton">
                    <div><p>Tab 2</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="tabButton">
                    <div><p>Tab 3</p></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS file

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body .tabButton {
    width:33.33%; 
    height:100%; 
    background-color:pink; 
    float: left;
    display:table;
}
body .tabButton div {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
body .tabButton div p {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
```

How to solve this? Make sure clean tab size.

Answer (score 1):

You actually specified yourself that the content is *not* to use 100% of the available with:

```
body .tabButton {
    width:33.33%;
```

3 * 33.33% is 99.99%, which is *not* 100%. Try changing that to 33.34% and you will see that the gap is gone. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8TPq/) to try it out yourself...

Comment: 3 * 33.34% = 100.02% which may cause the the third div to start a new line. I would suggest increasing the number of decimal 33.3333333% instead. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/BsBFH/

Comment: Well it "is clear" for me in the fiddle I provided, whilst it is not when I use the "33.33%" in there. The html structure looks fine to me, that is not the issue. Maybe you did not reload the styles after changing the width definition? You might have to do a _deep_ reload in your browser, since the style definitions are cached otherwise. This definately is the issue at hand, since the blue color you see clearly is the blue you defined as a background. So the inner `div`s do not cover all available space.

Comment: @arkascha are u using emulation screen with iPhone 5 in google chorme?

Comment: What? Of course not! If you have such a special situation you should _state that_ in your question! Maybe this is a bug in that software, I have no idea. I tested with a few normal browsers, they all show this is the issue. _Did_ you do a deep reload?